# Can IATS be used with Simple Donate Extension? - SOLVED

Tags: wordpress, contribution-page, iats, simple-donate-form

****ISSUE RESOLVED.  SEE COMMENTS BELOW****

We are using Civi 5.1 on WordPress 4.9.7

A month ago, we switched our payment processor to IATS which we really like.
Now we would like to simplify our donation pages with the Simple Donate extension.

Normally we would have what you see in screenshot number 1 .

When I install the IATS extension, that Simple Donate option is removed from the menu and the IATS option replaces it, as you see in screenshot number 2.

The question is, can IATS and Simple Donate be used together? How do I get both options to appear on the menu?

Thank you.

[image: screenshot number 1]

[image: screenshot number 2]

Comment: what happens if you go copy the SimpleDonate link before it goes from your menu and then visit that page - does it exist?

Comment: if you can then you can probably just add yourself a new link in the menu

Comment: Thank you.  You are right. I just added it to the menu manually.  I am going to be adding to someone else's question about Simple Donate in a minute.  Maybe you will be familiar with that.

Comment: I added above as an answer - can you pls access/+1 and help close this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest that if you can copy the SimpleDonate link before it goes from your menu and then assuming you can visit that page then you can probably just add yourself a new link in the menu

Comment: Sounds like the iATS extension doesn't do a good job of picking an id for its menu item. Thanks for the question and answer.